# Error while Building using iPhoneDistribution

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode, app-store-connect

My app is running fine in Simulator as well as device. Now I am trying to submit it to the app store by following the stpes on http://blancer.com/tutorials/i-phone/90196/submitting-iphone-apps-to-the-apple-app-store-–-a-step-by-step-guide/

I get the following errors while doing a Build (iPhoneDistribution)

```
#import <libxml/tree.h>
```

No such file or dir

The same error is not thrown when using Simulator/Device onwhich the app runs fine..

What is the cause of this error? Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check your configurations to make sure that they all have the same set of header search paths.

In xcode 3 get info on your target and select build settings. In xcode 4, select the project in the navigator, then build settings and target. type "header search" into the filtering text box at the top. There will be an entry for Header Search Paths. Make sure that all the build configurations have the same set of search paths.

Comment: Could you please be a bit more specific on this, like where do I need to go and check ?

Comment: in xcode 3 get info on your target and select build settings. In xcode 4, select the project in the navigator, then build settings and target. type "header search" into the filtering text box at the top. There will be an entry for Header Search Paths. Make sure that all the build configurations have the same set of search paths.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that...The erroes have now gone...But I am getting "A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found." when trying to test the app for my device (i have selected iphoneDistribution)

Comment: Everything you need to know about provisioning is available here - https://developer.apple.com/ios/my/overview/index.action. Make sure you check out the section on verifying a successful build.